# How to create and call a JS function from another LWC?

Tags: lightning-datatable, datatable, sort

I want to create a utility class that has this two methods for order a datatable column:

```
function sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
    const key = primer
        ? function (x) {
              return primer(x[field]);
          }
        : function (x) {
              return x[field];
            };

            return function (a, b) {
                a = key(a);
                b = key(b);
                return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
            };
        }
    
    function onHandleSort(data, event) {
    const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
    const cloneData = [...data];

    cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
    data = cloneData;
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
}
```

I tried to export for many ways but its not working..

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use `this` inside the exported functions, because it'll refer to the wrong object, unless you take extra steps (e.g. using `bind`, `call`, or `apply`). That said, there's an easy way to fix this without much effort.

---

## util.js

```
function sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
  const key = primer? (x) => primer(x[field]): (x) => x[field]
  return ((a, b) => (a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a))))
}
export function onHandleSort(data, event) {
  const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
  const cloneData = [...data];
  cloneData.sort(sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1))
  const result = { data: cloneData, sortedBy, sortDirection }
  return result
}
```

---

## example.js

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { columns, fetchDataHelper, onHandleSort } from 'c/util';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
  columns = columns
  data = []
  sortedBy = 'name'
  sortDirection = 'asc'
  async connectedCallback() {
    this.data = await fetchDataHelper({ amountOfRecords: 10 })
  }
  handleSort(event) {
    Object.assign(this, onHandleSort(this.data, event))
  }
}
```

---

## example.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns} sorted-by={sortedBy} sorted-direction={sortDirection}
        onsort={handleSort} key-field="id">
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

[Run this example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/lGIG5Fp7oNFviGQ5NHGG/src/app.js?p=stories).

And yes, I'm aware that this example has a logic bug; the dollar amounts sort lexicographically. That's outside the scope of this answer, which is simply meant to demonstrate how to import/export functions.